# Press Keys and Scroll Element into view is not working in latest 91 & 92 Chrome Driver for Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Press Keys and Scroll Element into view Keywords are no more working in the latest Chrome Driver for Robot Framework.

Comment: I'd suggests logging that as a bug/starting a discussion in SeleniumLibrary's github https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary

Answer (score 0):

We've had luck with creating our own keyword to replace the one from SeleniumLibrary:

```
def scroll_element_into_view(self, locator):
    element = self.selenium.get_webelement(locator)
    self.selenium.driver.execute_script(
        "arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'auto', block: 'center', inline: 'center'})",
        element,
    )
```